# How to search a string into a string array using c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, algorithm

I need to search a string into a string array. In particular, I have a string variable with a name and I need to search this name into an array of string, but I am not able to resolve my problem.

Here's my code:

```
connessionesocket(sock,server);

    int result=0,f=0;
    bool trovato=false;
    do{ 

        if(result=(recv(sock, estratto, sizeof(estratto),0))>0)
        {
            string appo(estratto);
            cout << "Appo: "<< appo<< endl; 
            if ( std::find( std::begin( numeri ), std::end( numeri ), appo ) != std::end( numeri ) )
            {
                    cout << "Correct" << endl;  
            }   
            f++;                             
        }               

        if(result==0)
        {
            cout<< "Fine";
        }
    }
    while(result>0);
    close(sock);
```

what is the problem? why I don't see the `cout << "Correct" <<endl;`

this is my result:

[I need, so the result is the same of the matrix to see the **"Correct" message**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKxSy.jpg)

Comment: First off if `names[x]` and `appo` are `std::string`s get rid of `strcmp` and use `names[x] == appo`

Comment: Answer, with current context given, is easy - none of strings in `names` match `appo`.

Comment: @NathanOliver I try to do what you tell me but, my program is a client /server and when I do `names[x]==appo` my server stop to work..

Comment: @SilviaB then you have some other problems in your code, for example your arbitrary limit of 15 is not correct

Comment: Then I think you have bigger issues.  Changing your code to `names[x]==appo` should have no observable effect on how the code works expect it makes it clear what you are doing in the source.

Comment: @SilviaB You didn't transmit `std::string`s over the wire or something? (That doesn't work.)

Comment: @molbdnilo look the question, I add more info.. if you can help me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use standard algorithm `std::find`. For example

```
#include <algorithm>

//...

if ( std::find( names, names + 15, appo ) != names + 15 )
{
        cout << "Correct" << endl;  
}
```

Or if the range corresponds to the entire array then

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

//...

if ( std::find( std::begin( names ), std::end( names ), appo ) != std::end( names ) )
{
        cout << "Correct" << endl;  
}
```

Comment: I've a problem: when I launch the program starts the error that tell me that begin and end aren't members of std.. why?

Comment: @SilviaB You need to compile with at least c++11 enabled to use them.

Comment: @NathanOliver thanks but it doesn't work... I don't know why

Comment: @SilviaB Also check that you included header <iterator>

Comment: I add all libraries @VladfromMoscow

Comment: @SilviaB If the code does not compile then use the first example

Comment: @NathanOliver @VladfromMoscow is important if appo had undergone a transformation: `char estratto[2048];     string appo(estratto); `

Comment: @SilviaB I do not understand what problem do you have? Character arrays are implicitly converted to strings in the overloaded operator == of the class std::string.

Comment: @SilviaB Is `estratto` a valid null terminated string?  I have a feeling that sending the string is causing an issue trying to match it.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow for example.. If I use your code I've no problem but the cout doesn't see while if I modify your code and use `==` instesd `!=` I see the cout...

Comment: @NathanOliver `estratto` doesn't cause errors... it will be received correctly

Comment: @SilviaB I have understood nothing what you said.

Comment: Your code is correct and works but the `cout` doesn't work with the code!! @VladfromMoscow

Comment: @SilviaB I do not understand qwhat you mean.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow look the question I edited it with an image an more info.. maybe in this way you can understand and maybe you can help me

Comment: @SilviaB It is anorther question that has nothing common with the original question. It is a bad idea to change such a way questions. As for your modified question then the reason can be that none string is found in the array.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow ok I follow your advice!! But why doesn't found any string? How can I resolve this problem? I work for weeks at this program and the problem is always this.

Comment: @SilviaB I think it is enough to output the strings that to determine the problem.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Ok I tried and the results are thats: `appo = 17` while `numeri=0x7ffcb70a5f50` and my code is: `cout << "appo: "<< appo<< endl;      cout << "numeri" << numeri << endl;` ... How can I translate **numeri** into the correct form?

Comment: @SilviaB Try to ask a new question at SO.